# How to wire a dimmer switch to an exhaust fan

Tags: wiring, fans

Today I want to wire a dimmer switch inline between my exhaust fan and its 110v AC power source.

As you can see there is a black, white and green wire from the fan to the 110v AC power cable. These are wired as expected and as soon as I throw the switch on my power bar, the fan runs full speed.
The dimmer has 2 black wires, 1 red wire and 1 green wire.

I know green is ground, I want to know how to properly wire the white and back from the fan to the black and red of the dimmer.

I want to be able to control the fan speed.

I appreciate your insight!

[image: dimmer switch wires]

Comment: That dimmer is for incandescent lights only, not for fans.  You will need a switch made to adjust fan speeds.

Comment: From the image: *pour eclairage a incandescence seulement*, which Google translates as *for incandescent lighting only*.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to control the fan speed, you do not want a dimmer switch. Fan speed controls are a different class of product. [Here are some example devices](https://www.lutron.com/en-US/Products/Pages/StandAloneControls/FanControls/FanControls.aspx). It is running the fan at full speed because it does not have the proper circuitry to control motor speed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not use dimmer switch to control a motor.

Dimmer works by simply reducing the power, which dims the light. The light bulb does not mind since it is just stupid heating/glowing element.

However motor still needs full power to work correctly.

There are no hot/glowing elements in the motor.

In simple therm, the motor works by chasing the frequency (your 60 Hertz), thus rotating.

To do that it needs full power.

The motor speed controller works by regulating the frequency. So if you reduce the 60 Hz to 30 Hz the motor will go slower, it will not overheat or burn up.